Using R to scrape web table with accordion format
I am looking to use rvest to scrape the 'Monthly Cargo Volumes' data on https://www.panynj.gov/port/en/our-port/facts-and-figures.html. I believe I had the correct xpath but i am getting no results. Thank you.
library(rvest)
library(dplyr)

url <- 'https://www.panynj.gov/port/en/our-port/facts-and-figures.html'

schedule <- url %>% 
    read_html() %>%  
    html_nodes(xpath = '/html/body/div[1]/div/div/div[2]/div[62]/div[1]/div/div[1]/div/div[1]/div[5]/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/div/div/div/div[1]/div/table/tbody/tr[3]/td[2]') %>% 
    html_table() %>% 
    data.frame

Result:
data frame with 0 columns and 0 rows

The first issue is that the website isn't static but uses javascript to create the tables you want to scrape. To tackle this issue use read_html_live instead of read_html (which requires you have Chrome installed on your machine). Second, even with that change you will get an empty dataframe as you target a single table cell with your xpath expression instead of a table. As a result html_table will return nothing as the cell does not contain a table. Instead, to get the content of a single cell you can use html_text:
library(rvest)

url <- "https://www.panynj.gov/port/en/our-port/facts-and-figures.html"

schedule <- read_html_live(url) |>
  html_elements(
    xpath = "/html/body/div[1]/div/div/div[2]/div[62]/div[1]/div/div[1]/div/div[1]/div[5]/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/div/div/div/div[1]/div/table/tbody/tr[3]/td[2]"
  ) |> 
  html_text()

schedule
#> [1] "    3,737,112"


Thank you stefan.
My ultimate goal is to download all the tables under 'Monthly Cargo Volumes'. Would you recommend me looking for another xpath for the whole section, or do I just have to loop through all the xpaths along the way?
Thank you!

If you want all tables try read_html_live(url) |> html_table(). That will give you a list of all tables.
